Users Unable to Login via Firebase Authentication in Google Play Installed App
Users are unable to log in using Firebase Authentication when the app is installed from Google Play. However, the same app works correctly when running locally during development. All configuration settings have been double-checked and appear to be correct.
Firebase:
1A: Upload Key
2A: App Key
Keys are added to Firebase correctly.

Google Play Console:
1A: Upload Key
2A: App Key
Keys are added to Google Play Console correctly.

Google Cloud:
1A: Upload Key
2A: App Key
Keys are added to Google Cloud correctly.



Firebase App Check:
Firebase App Integrity was enabled and is now disabled.



Flutter Version
3.24.2
